# Thoughts on Entity Framework 5 and Multi-Threading

Tags: .net, multithreading, entity-framework-5, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0

I am writing a WinForms application using Visual Studio 2012 in C# (.NET 4.5) with Entity Framework 5.0 and SQL Server 2008.  Currently, I am using one database context for each form.  Each form displays the data for a single entity (I'll call it the "Parent Entity") in addition to it's related child entities (i.e., entity collections):

```
Parent Entity
     │
     ├─ Child Entities 1
     │
     ├─ Child Entities 2
     │
     ├─ Child Entities 3
     │
     └─ Child Entities 4
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a fast connection to the database and it takes a long time (about 30 seconds, which seems like forever for my users) to query the data and populate a form.  So, here's what I'm thinking:

Instead of using one database context per form, I want to create a database context for the Parent entity and separate database contexts for each of the Child Entity collections.  **I want to create these contexts on different threads** (or however the Thread Pool is going to allocate things) **and then return these contexts to the the form after they've been created.**  Please note the following conditions:

- At no time will more than one thread interact with a database context.
- The separate database contexts will remain separate (even after being returned to the main form) and they will not interact with each other.

Once the user has made all their changes, I plan to wrap the SaveChanges() event for each context in a transaction:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    parentContext.SaveChanges();

    childContext1.SaveChanges();
    childContext2.SaveChanges();
    childContext3.SaveChanges();
    childContext4.SaveChanges();

    scope.Complete();

}
```

Basically, my questions are as follows:

- Will this work?
- Is there any reason why this approach is bad?
- What would you recommend in this situation?

Comment: _Unfortunately, I don't have a fast connection to the database and it takes a long time (about 30 seconds, which seems like forever for my users) to query the data and populate the form._ Create a local mirror or cache? Or you can be looking into reducing number of queries — either find a way to batch them with EF, or use custom LINQ/SQL to get everything at once (I do not know EF that well to tell how exactly).

Comment: @Andrey_Shchekin  Thanks for commenting.  The suggestion of creating a local mirror is good one, however, this application will be used by multiple locations which will require multiple local mirrors...this will be a nightmare to synchronize and maintain.  Also, there is the issue of concurrency.

Comment: Is the connection speed non-negotiable? I think what you propose is doable under the conditions you describe. The drawback is that you build a quite an intricate structure that you won't easily change in the future if the network speed improves. So it will always be a potential source of bugs that may be hard to tackle and maintenance will be less than trivial. On the other hand, it will be also be useful with a better connection speed. An improvement could be to work with disconnected DTO/Viewmodel objects, populated by multiple contexts and save changes through one new context instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An improvement could be to work with disconnected DTO/Viewmodel objects, populated by multiple contexts and to save changes through one new context instance.

Each object (`Parent` and each `Child`) will be represented by a DTO class where `ParentDto` has collections of `ChildDo`s. You populate the parent by one context, which is disposed afterwards, and the children each by their own short-lived contexts in separate threads.

When you save changes you can write changes in the DTOs to their entity counterparts and save through one context that is newed up for that target.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, Gert...I really appreciate it!  Cheers!!